# In which way does this post answer the question?

Tags: discussion, answers

I was looking for the questions using [integration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration), and found [Forum CMS for Drupal user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18789/forum-cms-for-drupal-user) which has [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/18794/199).
That post doesn't answer the question, which is about modules handling a forum, or a Wiki-style site. It just says something that could be said for every project; the suggestion that Drupal could not be the best tool doesn't seem appropriate for *Drupal Answers*, for such simple tasks.

If the answer has been given because the question was too generic, then the question should be closed.
Still, it doesn't seem the question has been voted to be closed, nor did the answer get flagged as not an answer.

Does the answer really answer the question? Do we want such answers, on *Drupal Answers*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @googletorp on this one, and I vaguely recall reading this question at the time.

The root problem is the question itself.  The OP admits that they don't know what they want in the first sentence.

It should have either been reworded as

> I would like to do foo, what is the best Drupal approach for doing so?

or it should have been broken down into two questions

> Are Drupal's forum modules sufficiently good for an advanced forum site?  If not, are they any contrib modules that provide a good forum experience?

and

> Is it possible to create wiki sites with Drupal?  Which modules help with this?

One person up-voted it.  I didn't consider it a good question, so I didn't up-vote it, but I thought it could solicit good answers so I didn't vote to close or flag for attention.

The answer that you pointed to is a decent answer for the problem at hand.  A better answer would have mentioned how to build a forum and/or wiki and then said how you need to determine requirements before picking a solution.  I up-voted it, though.  Four other people agreed, and so did the OP who accepted it.   See also [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer)

I thought the other answer was good, too, and up-voted it.

Answer (score 0):

What better judge than the user that asked the question is there to determine if the question was answered?

Anyways, we should never censor posts because they are not *good enough* that's what we have the up/down vote system for.

Comment: It's not about censorship; it's about users not flagging as not an answer what doesn't answer the question, or not closing a question that needs to be closed. Following your reasoning, there should not be a "not an answer" flag, as answers could be down-voted, even when the answer is a completely different question. The problem I see is that such answer could be given for every question where the OP is interested of passing to Drupal; I don't think that answer would be helpful for the OP. I am not talking about censorship.